# How to ban the ip trying to login my postfix?

Tags: linux, iptables, postfix

Os : centos7.

```
 tail -f /var/log/maillog

Oct 30 07:18:13 localhost postfix/smtpd[3181]: warning: unknown[191.96.249.63]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Oct 30 07:19:12 localhost postfix/smtpd[3181]: warning: unknown[191.96.249.70]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Oct 30 07:21:00 localhost postfix/smtpd[3184]: warning: unknown[41.191.224.5]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
```

How to ban the ip trying to login my postfix?
I have read some material that postfix can set blacklist to ban some ip address.
Are they the same effect between banning it with iptable and banning it with postfix's blacklist setting?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/576751/example-of-fail2ban-configuration-to-ban-servers-spamming-my-postfix-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use iptables (Linux's built-in firewall), then you can configure a rule to drop all packets coming from that IP.

The command is:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s IP-ADDRESS -j DROP
```

It's meaning is:

```
iptables - the name of the command which manages iptables.
-A - Appends the rule.
INPUT - is the name of the chain where the rule will be appended to.
-s - Defines source address.
IP-ADDRESS - The address you want the rule to affect on.
-j - Specifies the target of the rule
DROP - The action to take
```

Then, run the following command to apply the change:

```
service iptables save
```

In your case, the commands would be:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 191.96.249.63 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 191.96.249.70 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 41.191.224.5 -j DROP
service iptables save
```

There's another thing you can do, and that is to install [Fail2Ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), which will automatically ban malicious IP's, I recommend you to check it out, otherwise you will spend all day long banning specific IP's.

Comment: I have read some material that postfix can set blacklist to ban some ip address.      
Are they the same effect between banning it with iptable and banning it with postfix's blacklist setting?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, I just know that it's a more common solution to block malicious IP's using iptables than postfix blacklist option.

Comment: There's another tool called SpamAssassin, you may want to check it as well. This is a comparison between spamassassin and fail2ban: https://sysadmin.libhunt.com/project/fail2ban/vs/spamassassin